# change password from database according to different id beginnings

Tags: java, mysql, database, drag-and-drop

i have 3 tables (doctor , nurse , patient) all of them have different id beginnings , doctors id start with 101 , nurse start with 102 , and patient start with 200 .
and i want to change the password according to the beginnings of their id .
in my JFrame i have 5 JComponents , 4 Jtextfields , 1 Jbutton 
1 Jtextfields for the id (name : idField )
1 Jtextfields for the current password (name : currentPass)
2 Jtextfields for the new password ( name : newPass1 , newPass2)
1 Jbutton for the action ( name : changeButton )

i did 2 different ways in my code , but both did't work with me .
can you help me with this problem ?

first way :

```
private void changeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
       id=idField.getText();
       newpass1=newPass1.getText();
       newpass2=newPass2.getText();

        try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/hj", "xxx", "xxx");
        st = con.createStatement();

        if (newpass1.equals(newpass2)){


          ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("update patient set patient_Password="+ newpass1 +" where patient_Id="+id+" and patient_Id like '200%'");  
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this , "Successfully changed", "Patient password successfuly changed !",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

          ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery("update Nurse set nurse_password="+ newpass1 +" where nurse_id="+id+" and nurse_id like '102%'");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this , "Successfully changed", "Nurse password successfuly changed !",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

            ResultSet rs2 = st.executeQuery("update doctor set doctor_password="+ newpass1 +" where doctor_id="+id+" and doctor_id like '101%'");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this , "Successfully changed", "Doctor password successfuly changed !",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        } else 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this , "Not equal", "Your new passwords are not equal!! , try again",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
       }catch (Exception x){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, x.getStackTrace());
       }
    }
```

second way :

```
 private void changeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
       id=idField.getText();
       newpass1=newPass1.getText();
       newpass2=newPass2.getText();

        try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/hj", "xxx", "xxx");
        st = con.createStatement();

        if (newpass1.equals(newpass2)){

        if (id.startsWith("200")){
          ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("update patient set patient_Password="+ newpass1 +" where patient_Id="+id+"");  
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this , "Successfully changed", "Patient password successfuly changed !",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        } 
        else if (id.startsWith("102")){
          ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("update Nurse set nurse_password="+ newpass1 +" where nurse_id="+id+"");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this , "Successfully changed", "Nurse password successfuly changed !",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                }
        else if (id.startsWith("101")){
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("update doctor set doctor_password="+ newpass1 +" where doctor_id="+id+"");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this , "Successfully changed", "Doctor password successfuly changed !",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }

        } else 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this , "Not equal", "Your new passwords are not equal!! , try again",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
       }catch (Exception x){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, x.getStackTrace());
       }
    }
```

Comment: You should escape the `varchar` values with `'` . Better yet, consider using a `PreparedStatement` which will escape values for you (and prevent SQL injection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do use `PreparedStatement`!

```
    if (id.startsWith("200")){
      try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE patient SET patient_passwort=? WHERE patient_id=?");) {
          pstmt.setString(1, newpass1);
          pstmt.setString(2, id);
          int rows = pstmt.executeUpdate();

          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this , "Successfully changed", 
             "Patient password successfuly changed! (updated rows: "+rows+")", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
       }
    }
```

By concatenating the query, you'll get `update patient set patient_Password=abcdefghi where patient_Id=200340 and patient_Id like '200%'`.
The new password (here `abcdefghi`) is not quoted, which is mandatory for strings in queries. The `patient_id` is also not quoted, but it's possibly a number field, which has not to be quoted.

BTW:

- the query part `patient_id like '200%'` is not needed.
- You should close any PreparedStatement/Statement instances, which can be done by using try-with-resources (`try (PreparedStatement xxx = ...) { ... your code } // closes automatically`). Same goes for `Connection` and for `ResultSet`.
- since the `id` is an integer, you might want to use it as such: `int updId = Integer.parseInt(id); ... pstmt.setInt(2, updId); ...`

Tipp: 
You'll ease your life even more, if you use Apache commons-dbutils. e.g. `org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner`

```
  QueryRunner r = new QueryRunner();
  int rows = r.update(conn, 
       "UPDATE patient SET patient_passwort=? WHERE patient_id=?",
       newpass1, id);
```

Comment: thanks that was so helpful , and it did work , thank you :)